# Mocking instance method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Maybe I am missing something, can someone tell me why this unit test case does not work?

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class A {
    private B b;

    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }

    public int methodA() {
        return b.methodB();
    }

}
```

// just returns a random number

```
class B {
    public int methodB() {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }
}
```

// this is my test method and it does not print 20

```
    @Test
    public void testMethodA() {
        B b = Mockito.mock(B.class);
        Mockito.when(b.methodB()).thenReturn(20);

        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.methodA());
    }
```

Comment: The mock isn't being inserted in `A`, so `A` still instantiates a new `B` when you call its constructor.  One common way of doing this is to pass an already-created `B` into `A`'s constructor.  So after you create your mock, you can do `A a = new A(b);`

Comment: I am always amazed how many people just start using mocking frameworks ... without first studying a good tutorial. These things are *complicated*. Dont assume that you can *anticipate* how to do things. Any good tutorial would carefully explain to you that just creating a mocked object alone doesnt magically push that mocked object into some other object ...

Answer (score 0):

The class `A` instantiates its own instance of `B`, so your mock instance is never used. Instead you can refactor `A`'s constructor to take a factory for `B` objects or an instance of `B` which it will use internally.

To do what you're describing originally, you could replace the method completely using PowerMock.

```
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTests {
    @Test
    public void myTest {
        // Make B.methodB always return 20
        PowerMock.stub(PowerMock.method(B.class, "methodB")).toReturn(20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mock when you're injecting beans. In here you are manually creating a B class instance. So your mock won't effective here.